# Why do I keep getting this error: exception Unhandled : Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation. this was 0x4

Tags: c++

I am currently working on the BlackJack project, but there is an error showing "exception Unhandled: Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation. this was 0x4.". I am not quite sure which part I did wrong, and the program sometimes runs normally sometimes shows that exception.  In draw_card function, it returns a value of a random number. For example: if we get 13, the value will be 10. It also returns the name of the card and the type of the card such as 13 corresponds to king.

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    unsigned bet;
    int player = 0 , dealer = 0;
    string card , type;

    cout << "You have $100. Enter bet: ";
    cin >> bet;
    
    cout << "Your cards are:" << endl; 
    player += draw_card(card, type, player);
    cout << "  "+card + " of " + type << endl;
    player += draw_card(card, type, player);
    cout << "  " + card + " of " + type << endl << endl << endl;
}

int draw_card(string& card, string& type, int drawer_points) {
    int randomNumber;  //between 1 and 13
    int suite;         //between 1 and 4 to determine the suite of the card.

    randomNumber = rand() % 13 + 1;
    suite = rand() % 4 + 1;
    
    card = getRank(randomNumber);
    type = getSuit(suite);

    if (randomNumber == 13 || randomNumber == 12 || randomNumber == 11) {
        return 10;
    }else if (randomNumber == 1) {
        int ace1 = 21 - (drawer_points + 1);
        int ace2 = 21 - (drawer_points + 11);

        return ace1 < ace2 ? 1 : 11;
    }
    else
    {
        return randomNumber;
    }
}


string getSuit(int suit) {
    
    switch (suit)
    {
    case 0:
        return "spades";
        break;
    case 1:
        return "clubs";
        break;
    case 2:
        return "diamonds";
        break;
    case 3:
        return "hearts";
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    
}

string getRank(int rank) {
    switch (rank)
    {
    case 13:
        return "King";
        break;
    case 12:
        return "Queen";
        break;
    case 11:
        return "Jack";
        break;
    case 1:
        return "Ace";
        break;
    case 2:
        return "Two";
        break;
    case 3:
        return "Three";
        break;
    case 4:
        return "Four";
        break;
    case 5:
        return "Five";
        break;
    case 6:
        return "Six";
        break;
    case 7:
        return "Seven";
        break;
    case 8:
        return "Eight";
        break;
    case 9:
        return "Nine";
        break;
    case 10:
        return "Ten";
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of the exception? Please provide more info about the error message. Also, you can use your debugger to step through your program and see where exactly the exception is thrown.

Comment: What does `getSuit` return if `suit` is not 0, 1, 2, or 3? What are the possible values of `rand() % 4 + 1`?

Comment: In a `case`, if it does a `return` through all code paths, it need not do a `break`.  That's just noise.

Comment: Side note: When you see something with a ridiculously low address like *this was 0x4*, go looking for a null pointer. You've usually got a null plus an offset.

Comment: @OP [Your compiler should have warned you about this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbce3860d96cce97).  Did you ignore the warning, or did the compiler issue this warning or similar warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generate

```
suite = rand() % 4 + 1;
```

This is a random number between 1 and 4 inclusive.

You then call

```
getSuit(suite);
```

But `getSuit` only has switch branches for values between 0 and 3 inclusive:

```
switch (suit)
{
case 0:
    return "spades";
    break;
case 1:
    return "clubs";
    break;
case 2:
    return "diamonds";
    break;
case 3:
    return "hearts";
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

Not returning a value from a function that is declared to return a value is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

A few functions like `getSuit` and `getRank` in your code don't return a value if only the default case of their `switch` statement is executed.

You can return an empty string in the default cases:

```
default:
        return ""; // empty string
```

And in the call site, check to see if the returned value is empty using the `empty` function.

Another way is to use `std::optional<T>` like below:

```
std::optional<string> getSuit( const int suit )
{
    switch (suit)
    {
    case 0:
        return "spades";
    case 1:
        return "clubs";
    case 2:
        return "diamonds";
    case 3:
        return "hearts";
    default:
        return { }; // empty optional
    }
}
```

And in the call site:

```
std::optinal<std::string> type { getSuit(suite) };

if ( type ) // if optional has value
{
    // extract and use the value inside of optional
    type.value( );
}
```

Keep in mind that if the optional does not have a value, using `value()` will throw. You can use `value_or()` instead which does not throw.

Comment: `std:::optional` is a little overkill for a `std::string`, which has its own concept of emptiness. You could just return `""` or `{}` as a plain `std::string` instead, and then test `type.empty()`

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Yes right.